# How to override Magento 2 REST API Product Search Results for Custom Attributes?

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api, catalogsearch

Magento 2 REST API returns product search results (`V1/products`) for custom attributes in the following way by default (exemplary product):

```
{
  ...
  "custom_attributes": [
    {
      "attribute_code": "description",
      "value": "<p>The sporty Joust Duffle Bag can't be beat - not in the gym, not on the luggage carousel, not anywhere. Big enough to haul a basketball or soccer ball and some sneakers with plenty of room to spare, it's ideal for athletes with places to go.<p>\n<ul>\n<li>Dual top handles.</li>\n<li>Adjustable shoulder strap.</li>\n<li>Full-length zipper.</li>\n<li>L 29\" x W 13\" x H 11\".</li>\n</ul>"
    },
    {
      "attribute_code": "image",
      "value": "/m/b/mb01-blue-0.jpg"
    },
    {
      "attribute_code": "small_image",
      "value": "/m/b/mb01-blue-0.jpg"
    },
    {
      "attribute_code": "thumbnail",
      "value": "/m/b/mb01-blue-0.jpg"
    },
    {
      "attribute_code": "required_options",
      "value": "0"
    },
    {
      "attribute_code": "has_options",
      "value": "0"
    },
    {
      "attribute_code": "url_key",
      "value": "joust-duffle-bag"
    }
  ]
}
```

What to do if I want to return it in the following way:

```
{
  ...
  "custom_attributes": [
      "description": "value": "<p>The sporty Joust Duffle Bag can't be beat - not in the gym, not on the luggage carousel, not anywhere. Big enough to haul a basketball or soccer ball and some sneakers with plenty of room to spare, it's ideal for athletes with places to go.<p>\n<ul>\n<li>Dual top handles.</li>\n<li>Adjustable shoulder strap.</li>\n<li>Full-length zipper.</li>\n<li>L 29\" x W 13\" x H 11\".</li>\n</ul>",
      "image": "/m/b/mb01-blue-0.jpg",
      "small_image": "/m/b/mb01-blue-0.jpg",
      "thumbnail": "/m/b/mb01-blue-0.jpg",
      "required_options": "0",
      "has_options": "0",
      "url_key": "joust-duffle-bag"
  ]
}
```

or:

```
{
  ...
  "description": "value": "<p>The sporty Joust Duffle Bag can't be beat - not in the gym, not on the luggage carousel, not anywhere. Big enough to haul a basketball or soccer ball and some sneakers with plenty of room to spare, it's ideal for athletes with places to go.<p>\n<ul>\n<li>Dual top handles.</li>\n<li>Adjustable shoulder strap.</li>\n<li>Full-length zipper.</li>\n<li>L 29\" x W 13\" x H 11\".</li>\n</ul>",
  "image": "/m/b/mb01-blue-0.jpg",
  "small_image": "/m/b/mb01-blue-0.jpg",
  "thumbnail": "/m/b/mb01-blue-0.jpg",
  "required_options": "0",
  "has_options": "0",
  "url_key": "joust-duffle-bag"
}
```

I will be grateful for working solutions or any clues.

Answer (score 3):

you can achieve this by creating your own module.

- Create an endpoint in 'webapi.xml'
- implement your own repository
- Create custom Interface thats holds data structure
- Repository method ie: getList must return your Interface[]